# Communicate between parent and child component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just meet a problem about communication between parent and child component in React.

**Child**

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            childState: this.props.state,
        };
    },
    changeState(e) {
        this.setState({e.target.id});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button id='1' onClick={this.changeState}>1</button>
            <button id='2' onClick={this.changeState}>2</button>
        );
    },
});
```

**Parent**

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            parentState: '1',
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Child state=this.state.parentState />
        );
    },
});
```

So right now Parent will pass the initial state '1' to child, I want the child component can change both child and parent's state. For example, when click the second button, both child and parent state are set to '2'. How can I achieve this? Thank guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to achieve this behaviour you need to communicate with your parent component through props.

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button id='1' onClick={this.props.changeState}>1</button>
            <button id='2' onClick={this.props.changeState}>2</button>
        );
    },
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            parentState: '1',
        };
    },
    changeState: function(){
      this.setState({parentState: e.target.id});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Child changeState={this.changeState} state={this.state.parentState} />
        );
    },
});
```

The idea behind this is, that you are passing down the changeState function from your parent Component to your child Component as a function and make it accessible through props. That way when you call the prop function in your child Component - the function in the parent Component will get executed.

That way you also don't need to keep a second "separate" state in your child component because the state of the parent component will be available in both and have the same value in both.

Pardon me for any typing mistakes - I am at the office but since you had no answer yet I wanted to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How about child state? Looks like right now in child component, onClick calls parent's function, so I cannot call its own function to update it state.

Comment: As far as I understood your question you wanted to change the parent and child state at one click so that both have the same state accessible. Thats exactly it :) - you can now access the state in the child component with this.props.state

Comment: yes, that's right. Thanks! This completely solve my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :)